# Using depth buffer in opengl es 2.0 iphone

Tags: iphone, depth-buffer, opengl-es-2.0

I followed a tutorial using depth buffer in opengl es 1.1. But I use opengl es 2.0. The implemented code results in an error: Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6.
See implemented code below:

```
 (void)createFramebuffer
{
   if (context && !defaultFramebuffer)
   {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

        // Create default framebuffer object.
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);

        // Create color render buffer and allocate backing store.
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);

        // Create depth render buffer
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);

        [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &framebufferWidth);
        glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &framebufferHeight);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);


        if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
            NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    }
}
```

Regards
Niclas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you’re twice binding storage to your Depth renderbuffer, and never to your Color renderbuffer. The `-renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:` message to your EAGLContext binds a storage to the currently bound renderbuffer, which in your case is the Depth renderbuffer. Following, you’re binding storage to it again using the `glRenderbufferStorage` call.

The solution is to bind the Color renderbuffer prior to sending the storage message, so that the storage gets bounds to that. That is, insert a line `glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorRenderbuffer);` directly above the message, after you create your Depth renderbuffer. It should work, I was able to reproduce your error and subsequently solve it in this way.

*NB. Always make sure the correct buffers are bound. You can check using `glGetIntegerv()` for the binding, and `glGetRenderbufferParameteriv()` for additional parameters.*

Comment: Hi, yes I switched places and put all depth_buffer code last, so it worked. But thank you for the explanation.